# Custom field in the form not saving values in to the Database in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, checkbox

I have created a `custom attribute` for customer using below code.

> setup/installData.php

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'samsung', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Samsung ',
        'input' => 'boolean',
        'source' => '',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'position' => 166,
        'system' => false,
        'backend' => ''
    ]);


    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'samsung')
        ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'adminhtml_checkout',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]]);
    $attribute->save();
```

I am using below front-end code but data is not stored in the database:

```
<div class="field apple">
    <div class="control">
        <input type="checkbox" name="acs" id="apple" value="Apple" class="checkbox">apple
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field samsung">
    <div class="control">
        <input type="checkbox" name="acs" id="samsung" value="Samsung" class="checkbox">Samsung
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field sony">
    <div class="control">
        <input type="checkbox" name="acs" id="sony" value="Sony" class="checkbox">Sony
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field dell">
    <div class="control">
        <input type="checkbox" name="acs" id="dell" value="Dell" class="checkbox">Dell
    </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick='selectAll()' value="Select All"/>
    <input type="button" onclick='UnSelectAll()' value="Unselect All"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectAll(){
            var items=document.getElementsByName('acs');
            for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                if(items[i].type=='checkbox')
                    items[i].checked=true;
            }
        }

        function UnSelectAll(){
            var items=document.getElementsByName('acs');
            for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                if(items[i].type=='checkbox')
                    items[i].checked=false;
            }
        }           
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is the code for saving? Write that too.

Answer (score 1):

**please use below code:**

```
    <div class="field apple">
        <div class="control">
            <input type="checkbox" name="apple" id="apple" value="1" class="mycustomclass">Apple
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field samsung">
        <div class="control">
            <input type="checkbox" name="samsung" id="samsung" value="1" class="mycustomclass">Samsung
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field sony">
        <div class="control">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sony" id="sony" value="1" class="mycustomclass">Sony
        </div>
        </div>  
    <input type="button" onclick='selectAll()' value="Select All"/>
    <input type="button" onclick='UnSelectAll()' value="Unselect All"/>

    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#btn_checkall").click(function() {
    jQuery("input.mycustomclass").each(function() {
      jQuery(this).prop("checked", true);
    });
  });
  jQuery("#btn_uncheckall").click(function() {
    jQuery("input.mycustomclass").each(function() {
      jQuery(this).prop("checked", false);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```